# Where is proper place to install AsyncIOMainLoop() for Tornado application

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

So I have doubts what of 2 approaches to install AsyncIOMainLoop() I saw is more true. Which of them is more appropriate ?

**1st** When AsyncIOMainLoop() installed in make_app() code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.write("OK")

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.write("OK")

def make_app():
    tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler),],
                                   debug=False)

def start_app():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_app()
```

**2nd** when AsyncIOMainLoop() installed in start_app() code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.write("OK")

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.write("OK")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler),],
                                   debug=False)

def start_app():
    tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_app()
```

What do you think what of these 2 approaches is more appropriate ?

With 1st one I have troubles with running more than 2 tests in one **AsyncHTTPTestCase** suite with error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kamyanskiy/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-0zFWLpVX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 380, in setUp
    self._app = self.get_app()
  File "/home/kamyanskiy/work/test/test_app.py", line 10, in get_app
    return web1.make_app()
  File "/home/kamyanskiy/work/test/web1.py", line 74, in make_app
    tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
  File "/home/kamyanskiy/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-0zFWLpVX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 181, in install
    assert not IOLoop.initialized()
AssertionError
```

With 2nd one, when AsyncIOMainLoop() is installed in start_app() code - tests are running ok, but here I have doubts that during tests AsyncIOMainLoop() is not used.

Tests looks like:

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
import web1

class TestTornadoAppBase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return web1.make_app()

    # I have to uncomment this for 1st code example 
    # def tearDown(self):
    #    self.io_loop.clear_instance()  
    #    super().tearDown()

class TestGET(TestTornadoAppBase):
    def test_root_get_method(self):
        response = self.fetch("/")
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.body.decode(), 'OK')

    def test_root_post_method(self):
        response = self.fetch("/", method="POST", body='{"k": "v"}')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.body.decode(), 'OK')
```

So what is true way to select where to init AsyncIOMainLoop() ?

Comment: In your example, I cannot see any requirements that you need to install `AsyncIOMainLoop`.

Comment: @Sraw you are right, but this is simple example just like 'pseudo' code of project that I have to cover with tests, and there AsyncIOMainLoop is used to use aio libraries that requires asyncio loop, so Tornado app must be ran with AsyncIOMainLoop. It seems 100% less painful to use tornado's native ioloop.

Comment: So in this case, I think you need to override `get_new_ioloop`. ref: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase.get_new_ioloop

Comment: Another ref: https://gist.github.com/reinhrst/8775b63b1c369773e1f7

Comment: @Sraw thank you, good advice. So with get_new_ioloop() I always have AsyncIOMainLoop in tests, nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the 2nd example as the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html#tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop) says:

```
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
import asyncio
AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The point is that `AsyncIOMainLoop` has to be installed before you tell `asyncio` to run the loop.

Comment: thank you, I also more and more closer to take prefer 2nd way, but what do you think about that during tests AsyncIOMainLoop is not installed and instead of that native IOLoop is used ?

Comment: Have you tried installing `AsyncIOMainLoop` in `setUp()` method of your `TestTornadoAppBase` class?

Comment: in fact no, I override def get_new_ioloop(self): of AsyncHTTPTestCase and return AsyncIOMainLoop there. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693132/assertionerror-assert-not-ioloop-initialized-on-testing-tornado-app-with-asy/48701479#48701479)